# Intuit V2 to V3 API upgradation

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We are planning to upgrade our app from V2 to V3. I have read all the documents but there is nothing specific saying the issues of moving V2 to V3. V3 is REST based and V2 was based on QBXML so anything specific you want developers to note for upgrading the code to support V3? Also any upgrade tool would be awesome that can replace V2 to V3 would be very helpful to developers.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the following docs -

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/@api/deki/files/1463/gettingstartedwithquickbooks.pdf

JAVA/C#/PHP devkits and usage details are available here -

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits

PN - V2 and V3 both are REST based APIs.

If you have any entity specific qts then you can post it in IPP's live community.
https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/

Thanks

Comment: Manas ,thanks for your response. I have read all this and it looks like there will be lot of issues of upgrading v2 to v3 since field names are changes which is really really bad for V2 developers. Few e.g. are creditcardcharge in v2  is creditmemo in v3
companymetadata in v2  is companyinfo in v3. These are still manageable but my question is what about object structure, are there any changes in the XML schema that Intuit returns.

Comment: You can refer the latest V3 XSDs.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services#XML_Schema_Definition_Files

(V3_DataServices.zip)
 Object structures are different between V2 and V3. 

Thanks